# yum install mod_auth_token not working on CentOS

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

On CentOS 6.5 how do I make `yum install mod_auth_token` work these days? According to my own HOWTO I wrote 12 months back, you used to be able to just type it now you have to DIY it, which is bad because my DIY is bad, and I get this:

```
# cd   
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686.rpm
# rpm -Uvh mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
   libc.so.6 is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
   libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
   libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
   libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
   libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
# yum whatprovides libc.so.6
# yum install glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
# rpm -Uvh mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686.rpm
# yum install mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686.rpm
# rpm -ql mod_auth_token
/usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_auth_token.so
ls -l /etc/httpd/modules/
cp /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_auth_token.so /etc/httpd/modules/
```

but then I get this

```
 Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_auth_token.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_auth_token.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

so obviously I have somehow got a 64 bit/32 bit error. A year ago (I wrote to myself that) you could simply do

```
yum install mod_auth_token
```

is there a way to do this so it works? the `mod_auth_token.so` needs to be in `/etc/httpd/modules/`

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-i386/mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686.rpm.html) page:

Download the latest epel-release rpm from

> wget
>   http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

Install epel-release rpm:

> rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

Install mod_auth_token rpm package:

> yum install mod_auth_token

Comment: thanks man, I actually got the answer 2 hours later but SO wouldn't let me answer my own question :-/ (until today)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it easily because I used the 32 bit version url instead of the 64 bit version- for your edification to install mod_auth_token you can:

```
 # cd   
 # wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
 # rpm -Uvh mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
 error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6 is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.i686
 # yum whatprovides libc.so.6
 # yum install glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
 # rpm -Uvh mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

this below stuff was then not necessary

```
 # yum install mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
 # rpm -ql mod_auth_token
 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_token.so
 ls -l /etc/httpd/modules/
 cp /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_token.so /etc/httpd/modules/
```

NB: also I don't mention this but it is required to edit `conf/httpd.conf` and `conf.d/mod_auth_token.conf` but this is outside of the scope of my OP

Answer (score 0):

For **CentOS 7,**

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/33561557/dir/centos_7/com/mod_auth_token-1.0.5-2.1.x86_64.rpm.html

I was upgrading old server where I needed this mod_auth_token module for centos7.